# Restart and reformat section/heading numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a document with the following heading numbering system:

> 1. Chapter 1
> 2. Chapter 2
> 3. Chapter 3
> 4. Appendix 1
> 5. Appendix 2

I'm trying to change this to:

> 1. Chapter 1
> 2. Chapter 2
> 3. Chapter 3
>
> A1. Appendix 1
>
> A2. Appendix 2

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

- Click on your appendix header, to put the cursor in it
- On the "Styles" tab of the ribbon, look below the "Change Styles" button, to see a little arrow.
- Click the arrow to open the "Styles" dialog
- Click the "Manage Styles" button at the bottom
- Choose an appendix style, and it will be applied to the line where the cursor is

If there isn't an appendix style (there should be), you'll have to make a new one.